# PowerShell - Why is this not renaming my files?

Tags: powershell, scripting, rename, text-manipulation, file-manipulation

I have been looking around for a way to quickly and easily rename hundreds os files in one go.
something where I only have to change smalle parts for it to be reused somewhere else.
So i ended up starting to make this script. shown below...

the output should come out like this:

> `Show Title - SXX.EXXX - Episode title - [release year]`

the raw files all looks like this:

> `XXX  Episode title [release year]`

It does not work right now. and i haven't been able to see why yet.

*Whenever i run it, it does nothing. but i do not get any error message.*

```
$ShowTitle = "My Title -"
$SeasonNumber = "02" 

# Getting all child files (In ALL subfolders)
$files = Get-Childitem –Path Get-Location -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $_.Name -match $_.Name } | 

# Insert a ' - ' between the episode number and the episode text.
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName.insert(5,'-') + $_.Extension} |

# Append title and season number to the beginning of the file. 
Rename-Item -NewName  { $ShowTitle + "S" + $SeasonNumber + ".E" + $_.Name} | 

# Makes a "-" between episode title and year of release.
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\[', '- [' }
```

it worked on a smaller scale before. like this:

```
$files = Get-Childitem –Path "C:\Users\user\Videos\Series\show\Season x" -Recurse |
Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'show title' } | 
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\[', '- [' }
```

But i would like to do all the steps above in one go.

Can someone give me a hint so I can find the right answer to my little problem?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: @DougMaurer I did this to hit all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a lot of bugs here.

```
Get-Childitem –Path Get-Location -Recurse
```

This doesn't make sense. You're looking for a file or folder in the current directory with the *literal name* `Get-Location`. Like `C:\Get-Location\`. If you want to get the files in the current directory, you just don't specify the `-Path` parameter: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse`.

`Where-Object { $_.Name -match $_.Name }` is kind of nonsense code? The right hand side of the `-match` operator is going to be treated as a regular expression. That means `.` means "any character", square brackets and parentheses have special meaning, and so on. It's often going to *always* be true, but I can't imagine that you actually want to do what that says. It's very possible to construct a valid filename that doesn't match a regular expression with the same string value. For example `'[01] File.avi' -match '[01] File.avi'` is false.

Second, the `-NewName` parameter takes a string, while `{$_.BaseName.insert(5,'-') + $_.Extension}` is a ScriptBlock. That *may* work because some parts of Powershell allow that, but idiomatically I would say that it's wrong because it will not work consistently. A better option would be to use a string with embedded subexpressions like `-NewName "$($_.BaseName.Insert(5,'-'))$($_.Extension)"`

Finally, `Rename-Item` doesn't pass any output to the pipeline without the `-PassThru` parameter. You'd only process the first item and then I imagine the system would complain of an empty pipeline or only the first `Rename-Item` would do anything.

Try something like this:

```
$ShowTitle = "My Title -"
$SeasonNumber = "02" 

# Getting all child files (In ALL subfolders)
$files = Get-Childitem -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $_.Name -match 'some value or delete this command if you want all files' } | 

# Insert a ' - ' between the episode number and the episode text.
Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.BaseName.Insert(5,'-'))$($_.Extension)" -PassThru |

# Append title and season number to the beginning of the file. 
Rename-Item -NewName "$($ShowTitle)S$($SeasonNumber).E$($_.Name)" -PassThru | 

# Makes a "-" between episode title and year of release.
Rename-Item -NewName "$($_.Name -replace '\[', '- [')" -PassThru
```

Comment: Thank you @BaconBits  for your help. 

But now I am getting a pipline error on line 3.
but why would i get an empty pipline error with the `Get-Childitem` command? 
I can see it returns my files if i run it. 

`$files = Get-Childitem -Recurse | `

Comment: @Kasper Try eliminating the comments and blank lines. They can interfere with pipelines sometimes.

Comment: I ende up doing this insted, it was a lot more effektive. `dir | Rename-Item -NewName {"Show Name - S02.E" + $_.name}` `dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '   ', ' - ' }` `dir | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\[', '- [' }` This way works for me. but I had to split it up in three commands though.